# Can you make fancyBox ignore title text when sizing media within an overlay?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using fancyBox 2.1.5 and displaying media with multi-line titles below them.

My problem is that fancyBox seems to be shrinking media in an attempt to fit long titles on-screen. Below I've attached screenshots from my iPhone, where it is most obvious.

Here the image is displayed at full size because I've removed the title:
[image: Image Without Title]

Here the image is shrunken, trying to account for the long title:
[image: Image With Title]

I'd like fancyBox to ignore the title text when sizing media and always show it at full size, as seen in the first image. I'm OK with having to scroll to read all the title text.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with having to scroll to read all the `title` text, then you can combine the `fitToView` and `maxWidth` options to have the size of your media the way you want it without ignoring the `title` like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    fitToView: false, // avoids media to shrink to fit in the viewport
    margin: [20, 60, 20, 60],
    maxWidth: "90%", // avoids bigger media to stretch outside the viewport boundaries 
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: "inside"
        }
    }
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw6L8/)</kbd>

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks so much!

Just wanted to comment and say I also added `maxHeight: "100%"` to prevent tall images from extending past the bottom, and that has also worked exactly as hoped; the image is fully enlarged (as the dimensions of the screen allow) and you can see the title peeking in at the bottom, allowing you to scroll if you'd like to read the rest.

This was just a guess though, so lmk if it's working by fluke or my understanding is off. Otherwise, thanks again.